# Using redis with Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, redis, homestead

I was searching but couldn't find any information about this. It looks like it should be working out of the box but for some reason its not...I'm using laravel homestead (with default redis connection options in my env) and ran only

```
composer require predis/predis
```

Now I tried sending queued email but nothing happens... Any idea how to check if redis is running fine ?
I tried same code with database queue driver and its running fine...

Comment: try the command `redis-cli` in the console and then write `ping` and press enter. You should get the response `pong` and if you get it then let me know

Comment: @lewis4u It say command not found for redis-cli

Comment: Then there is no redis installed at all

Comment: Or you are not executing the command at the right place

Comment: @lewis4u Hmm it say that redis comes preinstalled with Laravel Homestead and I tried to execute both in my project directory and in Homestead directory

Comment: Well I'm not sure for vagrant, I have installed everything on my own and when I open command line i write redis-cli and i get this: https://s29.postimg.org/mrsd2o8hj/Capture.png

Comment: @lewis4u Yeah you were right, I did not execute command at the right place, i had to ssh into vagrant first. But now Idk what are connection parameters since default ones are not working and there is no documentation on laravel homestead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141287/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-michael).

Comment: can you go into chat? maybe you don't have enough rep points?

Comment: @lewis4u haha I'm not sure

Comment: try to click on this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141287/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-michael and tell me what happens